# OS X Shift-Tab closes window after upgrading to Safari 5

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm running OS X 10.6.4. In various browsers (Firefox and Safari), pressing Shift-Tab closes all tabs and windows of the browser. This is contradictory to [Apple's keyboard shortcuts page](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1343), which describes Shift-Tab as navigate through controls in a reverse direction. I checked System Preferences - Keyboard - Keyboard Shortcuts and don't see any Shift-Tab mappings.

Is there a way to disable or change this? It's quite annoying to accidentally press Shift-Tab and have the entire browser shutdown.

**Follow up**: It seems Shift-tab will close any application that I'm in. System Preferences - Keyboard - Keyboard Shortcuts "Restore Defaults" doesn't seem to help.

**Follow up 2**: It seems that this may be [related to Safari 5](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=932832). I'd be interesting if anyone else is seeing this after upgrading to Safari 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can confirm that `Shift`+`Tab` works fine for me, running everything up-to-date.

Two things:

1. Create a brand-new account to test this behaviour. If it doesn't happen in that account, it's likely that you have some other background application causing the behaviour.
2. Go back to `Keyboard Shortcuts` and enable `All Controls` (at the bottom) and see if that fixes it (normally, `Shift`+`Tab` goes back in form controls).

   [image: Screenshot of preferences]

Comment: I used another account and had no problems. The problem is with Witch (http://manytricks.com/witch/). I'm now troubleshooting the issue with them.